# Track follow link events in JavaEditor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In an eclipse plugin I would like to track follow link events of the JavaEditor i.e. I want my plugin to be notified when a developer presses control and clicks on a java element.

I already get the window open events and therefore have the `IWorkbenchWindow` objects of the open JavaEditors.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I believe you need to add a dependency to

```
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor
```

and use the extension point

```
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors
```

Maybe this link will help as well: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_hyperlinkDetectors.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added a hyperlink detector to add my own hyperlinks. I can now detect it when someone clicks on my hyperlink but the other hyperlinks are still there. 

How would you suggest to proceed? write an own JavaEditor with custom links or is there a possibility to remove the original hyperlinks?

Comment: Hmm, I would start searching where you attached your detector: I guess there should be some kind of "HyperlinkHandler", but I'm not familiar with that stuff... Defining a new editor could bring a lot of new challenges, i.e. behaviors of the old one should mostly remain to not annoy any users etc... You could probably inherit from  some existing built-in editor.